# Are there any Theorems that explain what happens when one reflects one of the functions on the y axis in an integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, reflection

For the integral

$$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x) = W$$

a reflection on the y axis is done about a point P for f(x) returning

$$ \int_a^b f(P-x)g(x) dx=Y $$

So my question is ... are there any theorems that relate the values of the integrals W and Y without directly computing their values?

Something such as W= Y but Y has different bounds of integration , or W= (a constant)*Y

I have not been able to find anything on this on internet.

You time and help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $\int_a^b \dfrac{x^k}{k!}g(x)dx=g(b)\dfrac{b^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}-g(a)\dfrac{a^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}-\int_a^bg'(x) \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}dx$

$\int_a^bg'(x) \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}dx=g'(b) \dfrac{b^{k+2}}{(k+2)!}-g'(a) \dfrac{a^{k+2}}{(k+2)!}-\int_a^bg''(x)\dfrac{x^{k+2}}{(k+2)!}dx$

Comment: Not necessarily because to calculate W. You only need the information of f(x) lying inside [a,b]. That information may be vastly different from what it could be after you have made the reflection about P.

Answer (score 3):

Let $[a, b] = [0, 1]$, $P=1$. For all $W, Y$ let

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & x\in [0,1/2],\\ 0 & x\in (1/2,1].\end{cases}$$
and

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} W & x\in [0,1/2],\\ Y & x\in (1/2,1].\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\int_{0}^1 f(x) g(x) dx = W, \ \ \ \int_{0}^1 f(1-x) g(x) = Y.$$

So there cannot be any relationship between $Y, W$.

Comment: How could you assert there's no relationship based on what you've written?

Comment: Let say if there is a relation given by $Y = F(W)$ for some function $F$. Then From what I found, I can find $f, g$ so that (e.g.) $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx = 1$, $\int_0^1 f(1-x) g(x) dx \neq F(1)$. Thus $Y = F(W)$ is not satisfied. @Divide1918

Comment: So you've proven there's no function relationship between the definite integrals with identical bounds. However, is it possible that $Y_1=F(W)$ where $Y_1$ is basically the same as Y except the bound is different? Also, if we restrict the proprerties of f and g, such as continuity and/or n times differentiability, is it still impossible to find a relationship?